# Chrome console shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I've created extension and ported it for all browsers. My extension adds buttons above one of Georgian forum's textarea

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSwCO.png

But I have strange problem only with Google Chrome and Safari. If you click exactly on blue image (B) there is no error but if you click anywhere else on that button it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined error in console and automatically posts on that web-site.

Here is my extension's source http://pastebin.com/mxnBqDxS

Console shows that error is on 341 line  var replaced = wrapper.start+val.substring(start, end)+wrapper.end;

Do you have any ideas why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Consider posting less than 350 lines of code, and only post the relevant code (such as your onClick method)

Comment: I thought it would be easier to find problem if you can see the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is here:

```
var method = ev.target.parentNode.id;
var wrapper = this._WRAPPERS[method];
```

`wrapper` is not getting set which means that `_WRAPPERS[method]` does not exist.  You could put an alert in to show the value of method -- my guess is that would make the problem clear.